# how to check if node is none and compare its data to another node on the same if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I cannot find a way to simplify this code

```
def mergeLists(head1, head2):
    tempNode = returnNode = SinglyLinkedListNode(None)
    while head1 is not None or head2 is not None:
        if head2 is None:
            tempNode.next = head1
            head1 = head1.next       
        elif head1 is None:
            tempNode.next = head2
            head2 = head2.next
        elif head1.data <= head2.data:
            tempNode.next = head1
            head1 = head1.next           
        else:
            tempNode.next = head2
            head2 = head2.next
        tempNode = tempNode.next
    return returnNode.next
```

Originally I wrote one if statement and one else statement, if statement was:

```
if head2 is None or head1.data <= head2.data:
```

And that gave me a comparing Nonetype problem. I think although this version works but there should be a way to simplify it, can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save some code (and running time) by exiting the loop as soon as **one** of the two list references is `None`. This has some advantages:

1. You don't have to test inside the loop body whether one of these list references is `None`, because it is ensured neither is `None`.
2. After the loop you can append the remaining list nodes with just setting the `next` reference to that remaining list. Since that list already has its remaining nodes connected correctly, there is no need to iterate those.
3. You could remove some code duplication, and determine which is the list with the least value using an *index* that is 0 or 1, denoting which of the two it is. It can be the boolean expression denoting whether the second data is less than the first. If you also have the two list references in a list of two, then you can deal with the loop body's logic in one generic way.
4. Not a reduction of code, but I would use the name `tail` for denoting which is currently the tail node of the already merged part. This is more descriptive than `tempNode`. And `returnNode` is not really what it says, as you actually return the node **after** that, so I would suggest the name `beforeHead`

```
def mergeLists(head1, head2):
    heads = [head1, head2]  # Use a list
    tail = beforeHead = SinglyLinkedListNode(None)
    while all(heads):  # A more strict condition: exit when one head is None
        least = heads[0].data > heads[1].data
        tail.next = tail = heads[least]  # assignment is first to tail.next, then tail
        heads[least] = tail.next
    tail.next = heads[0] or heads[1]  # Attach the remaining nodes
    return beforeHead.next
```

Comment: If you strive to reduce code amount **this** much, you can remove `int(...)` call (because `bool` used in index context will be coerced to `int` automatically via `__index__` method) and merge two assignments into `tail.next = tail = heads[least]` (multi-assignment is evaluated left-to-right) :)

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks for these ideas. I have implemented them in an update.